# Telegram bot delete new message (python)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

How to make a bot delete a new or last message in a group

```
import telebot
import constants

bot = telebot.TeleBot(constants.token)

LAST_UPDATE_ID = bot.get_updates () [- 1] .update_id, 
LAST_UPDATE_ID = False
bot.getUpdates () [- 1] .update_id
```

Comment: Could you please provide some minimal working example?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) method:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Note that `message_id` should be `update.message.message_id`.